# Controlling IO Pins

Tags: python, windows, io

Just wondering if:

Is it possible to control IO pins on the motherboard (I.e. PCI pins) from python. Secondly, If it is possible, how would I achieve this? Which library would I use, or how would I accomplish this. (On the windows OS).

Thanks.

Comment: I think it isn't even possible using assembly. PCI pins are controlled by the bus controller.

Comment: Thanks for the response - So, is there any way I am able to program the bus controller? I do a bit of robotics using the Propeller Chip, and I am wondering if I am able to treat the motherboard of a computer like MCU in a sense. How would a graphics card driver (for example) control the graphics card if it didn't have access to the IO pins?

Comment: It frobs the interface on the other end of the bus. But it never *directly* touches the bus itself.